# $\int _{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx=\int _{\infty}^{-\infty}f(-x)d(-x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$, is $$\int _{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx=\int _{\infty}^{-\infty}f(-x)d(-x)$$ true? If it's true, please prove it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: When you write the question, you need to assume that the integral exists.

Comment: $\int_a^bf(-x)d(-x)=-\int_a^bf(-x)dx=\int_{-a}^{-b}f(x)dx$

Answer (score 1):

If the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \mathrm{dx}$ exists, then by substitution $t = -x$, you get immediately your equality.

If the integral doesn't exist, then your equality has no sense.